# Error when Executing R Code Nested IF Conditions

Tags: r

I am trying to execute below R code which is throwing error

```
if(as.Date(df$Start.Date[1])== as.Date(df$Completed.Date[1])) {
SHour = as.numeric(as.difftime(format(df$Start.Date[1],"%H:%M:%S"),units = "hours"))
CHour = as.numeric(as.difftime(format(df$Completed.Date[1],"%H:%M:%S"),units = "hours"))
if(SHour>=sh && CHour<=eh) { 
df$nHours[1] = as.numeric(difftime(df$Completed.Date[1],df$Start.Date[1],units = "hours"))
} elseif(SHour<=sh && CHour<=eh) { 
df$nHours[1] = as.numeric(sh-CHour) 
} elseif(SHour>=sh && CHour>=eh) { 
df$nHours[1] = as.numeric(eh-SHour) 
} else { 
df$nHours[1] = eh-sh
}
```

}

Error I am receiving:

Error: unexpected symbol in:
"        df$nHours[1] = as.numeric(difftime(df$Completed.Date[1],df$Start.Date[1],units = "hours"))
} elseif"

> ```
>     df$nHours[1] = as.numeric(sh-CHour)
> ```

Error: object 'CHour' not found

> ```
> } elseif(SHour>=sh && CHour>=eh) {
> ```

Error: unexpected '}' in "    }"

> ```
>     df$nHours[1] = as.numeric(eh-SHour)
> ```

Error: object 'SHour' not found

Can someone please help what I am doing wrong here in the nested If conditions?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can't perform a numeric operation on objects that aren't numeric. Try `as.numeric(sh) - as.numeric(SHour)`

Comment: Does `format(df$Start.Date[1],"%H:%M:%S")` work at all?

Answer (score 0):

There should be space in between else and if in elseif condition which I missed in my code. After giving the space my code is working fine.
Thank You.